# Screaming about null values in tradingview-lightweight-charts

Tags: javascript, tradingview-api

[image: So I logged all the values that are going in but none of them seem to be null]

I'm trying to plot data in my tradingview-lightweight-charts chart and some of the datasets show up properly but some of them don't. I check all datasets for null values but none of them are.

here is the code responsible:

```
function onSymbolSelected() {
    var selectedSymbol = document.getElementById('symbolDropdown').value;
    console.log(selectedSymbol);
    fetch('/get_data', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            symbol: selectedSymbol,
        }),
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        const mappedData = data.map(item => {
            console.log("time:", new Date(item.timestamp).getTime() / 1000);
            console.log("open:", item.open);
            console.log("high:", item.high);
            console.log("low:", item.low);
            console.log("close:", item.close);

            return {
                time: new Date(item.timestamp).getTime() / 1000,
                open: item.open,
                high: item.high,
                low: item.low,
                close: item.close,
            };
        });
        ohlcSeries.setData(mappedData);
    });
}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)